# Embedding/Including extra information in the rpm files

Tags: rpm

I've a problem where I need to embed/include some extra information 
inside an RPM package I'm building. I probably can use %changelog
directive inside the RPM specfile to include some information. Another way
I'm thinking is sourcecode controlled json/yml file that gets installed
as part of RPM install.

I am wondering if there are any better ways. Your help will be appreciated.
BAsically the extra info that I want to include is a list of fixes (alphanumeric numbers) that may get queried later.

Comment: Just include a file containing your extra data, that way you can be sure the data is accessible when installed on even if you delete all the traces of the `rpm` itself.

Comment: Include where? Can you elaborate? thanks.

Comment: in the `%files` section of your `.spec` file.

Comment: ah,cool - thank you.

Comment: This stuff would typically be in `/usr/share/packagename/`. As noted previously, a data file of some kind could be useful. Another option that I've done is to have the git hash in the description - you can pass it to `rpmbuild` - let me know if you want an example.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate if you give me an example with details.